# nginx reverse proxy rewrite path using map

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a nginx reverse proxy to rewriting a id in the path with an another id (also the domain). For example
https://somewhere.com/user/123/setting  --> https://somewhere.else.com/user/456/setting
But i am having difficult for the rewrite parts.  May someone help?

```
map $old_user_id $new_project_id {
    123        456;
    999        9876;
    12         56;
}

server {
    location ~ ^/api/(?<old_project_id>.+)/store {
        rewrite ^/api/[^/]+(/.*)/store ....... # how to rewrite with the map?
        proxy_pass http://somewhere.else.com/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `^/api/(?<old_project_id>.+)/store` regex pattern definitely does not match an example URI `/user/123/setting` from your question. Please clarify your question using valid example(s) and desired result, several examples will be better than a single one.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, the wrong regex was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The regex do not match the id in the example.
By changing the following, I am able to solve my issue

```
location ~ ^/api/(?<project_id>.+)/store {
    rewrite ^/user/(.*)/setting /user/$project_id_2/setting break;
    proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:8080;
}
```